# Google map and CSS

Tags: jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
    #one, #two { height: 80%; width: 80%; }
    #map_canvas { height: 50%; width: 50%; }
</style>
<!-- or 
<style type="text/css">

    #map_canvas { height: 500px; width: 500px; }
</style>

-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  };
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="one" data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>header</h1>
</div>

<div id="two" role="main">
    <div name="map-canvas" id="map-canvas"></div>   
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>footer</h4>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to put google map into the jquery mobile page.

Google map with % size doesn't show up.

Is this css problem?

Can you tell me how you go about to solve this issue?

(The other thing is that after few trial run, google gives me "Invalid or unauthorized API key error while other sample codes doesn't use the Key at all. Does google map api mandatory?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine when you fix the css selector to match the ID

Change:

```css
#map_canvas { height: 50%; width: 50%; }
    ^
```

To:

```css
#map-canvas { height: 50%; width: 50%; }
    ^
```

The mismatch meant element had no dimensions, otherwise using `%` sizing is not uncommon

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQacBXxjkRLh9IS2oHT4?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: also beware when switching mobile pages will need to `refresh` map after it is hidden

Comment: I don't have multi pages now but thank you. is refresh part of google map api?

Comment: yes...actually i think method is `resize` not refresh. Basically any change in container dimensions needs it if map has already been rendered

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this why don't you just try to use Google Map's share embedded code and there you won't be requiring such details. And in that iframe code you can specify the width and height in %.

Comment: At the same time I want to understand the issues with the current state.

Comment: Google map doesn't specifically require any API to be used in your code, and in case if you are using any API like Google or LindkedIn etc., then you need to use cache with them because these websites will automatically block your request and expire your token for the API after certain amount of requests. The best way to do this is to locate your location on Google map and then click on the Share button from there you can get the embedded link and in that link you can see the iframe. Just copy that iframe into your HTML and rest of the things will be done automatically by the iframe code.